# difference union vs or-clause

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

in Spark, what is the difference between an `union` and an `or-clause` ?

Let's take an example :

Here is my dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
    ('96','2e63e9f4-27ba-4f50-bc65-a97032a22096' ),
    ('55','4bced1f9-63ad-4ebb-bf34-5fd7ff52d8e2' ),
    ('47','6c5c8151-7891-4567-9d6a-8dace74904bd' ),
    ('90','781eb57d-0774-46c0-9366-13cbab6322c6' ),
    ('27','7eb27670-1e4d-422f-b4f6-f65461bbeda5' ),
    ('259','91646385-3446-42af-a823-33112645024b'),
    ('33','92c77bd9-373d-4d32-9f36-5fa3fc093cd6' ),
    ('96','c6bcc234-7cd7-4134-8f89-b8bb50ae5e0f' ),
    ('55','4ade739d-5115-439c-900e-09fc4cb25293' ),
    ('47','73a2e429-cadc-4afa-ade2-4251e3745a0c' ),
    ('90','c0246074-a899-4437-a461-26c9445822ef' ),
    ('27','a7f6bbfb-fc03-4d04-ab4a-8f58eaf55dd0' ),
    ('259','13bc9ef0-35a0-4f85-8017-55bb8dae6628'),
    ('33','c77c5580-494f-45bf-bb04-6683a9dcc425' ),
  ],
  ["ClientId", "PublicId"]
)
```

and my filter information :

```
my_filter = [
  ('33','92c77bd9-373d-4d32-9f36-5fa3fc093cd6' ),
  ('96','c6bcc234-7cd7-4134-8f89-b8bb50ae5e0f' ),
  ('55','4ade739d-5115-439c-900e-09fc4cb25293' ),
]
```

If I filter using `union`, I will do :

```
from functools import reduce

out_dataframe_1 = reduce(
            lambda a, b: a.union(b),
            (
                df.where(
                    "ClientId = '{ClientId}' and "
                    "PublicId = '{PublicId}'".format(
                        ClientId=ClientId,
                        PublicId=PublicId,
                    )
                )
                for ClientId, PublicId
                in my_filter
            )
        )

out_dataframe_1.collect()
```

If I do it with `or-clause`, i will do :

```
where_clause = ' or '.join(
  "(ClientId = '{ClientId}' and "
  "PublicId = '{PublicId}')".format(
    ClientId=ClientId,
    PublicId=PublicId,
  )
  for ClientId, PublicId
  in my_filter
)

out_dataframe_2 = df.where(where_clause)

out_dataframe_2.collect()
```

Which one is the best to use ? 
Is there any other way to perform a succession of filters ? Maybe a join would be the best ?

Comment: Take a look at the execution plans. One thing to note is that `union` does a `UNION ALL` (keeping duplicates), whereas using the 'OR' would not.

Comment: @pault I know that. I am in a case where both are giving the same results.

Comment: Interesting stuff, wonder whether I would comp up with it, but this is an existency check I  take it.

Comment: why the ' or 'on the second one?

Comment: it's just a dummy operation I assume?

Comment: not really filtering with union, rather 'collecting' those results passing thru the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a single filter statement instead of applying 3 filters and unionizing results should be faster and is easier to read. You can also use 'in' to combine filter conditions:

```
where_clause = "(ClientId, PublicId) in ({})".format(', '.join(str(r) for r in my_filter))
df.where(where_clause).collect()
```

In case your filter statement gets too big you might want to make my_filter a dataframe and use it in a left_semi join.